# regex to help strip plaintext chat log?

Tags: javascript, regex, notepad++, corpus

So, I have a plaintext file of messages exported from Microsoft Lync. Basically, I took the source code and stripped the HTML. It looks something like this:

```
Smith, Joe [10:48AM]:
Hey guys!
How's it going?
Smith, Jane [10:49AM]:
Hey!
Doe, John [10:50AM]:
Wassup!
Where are we going out today?
```

So as you can see, they're all butted up against eachother, but more importantly, some users messages are multiple lines.

What I would like to do is create a regex expression to assist in a notepad++ macro that will go through and strip out everything but a certain user's messages, excluding their name and the time stamp.

So, for my example above, if my user was John Doe, the result I want would look like this:

```
Wassup!
Where are we going out today?
```

I'm looking for a regex that will basically target all users but John Doe so I can go through and delete all messages but his (I can strip his name and timestamp afterwards). The thing is, because some messages are multi-line, I need some way to say "Select this user, and all lines of their messages until the next user". Perhaps this would be easier with Javascript or something, but I feel like it should work this way as well.

Answer (score 0):

With Notepad++, just replace many times:

```
^.*\[.*[AP]M\]:\r\n(?:[\w\W]*?SURNAME, NAME \[.*[AP]M\]:((?:(?!.*\[.*[AP]M\]).*)*)|(?![\w\W]*\[.*[AP]M\]:)[\w\W]*)
```

with `$1`, substituting `SURNAME` and `NAME` with the ones you need.

You have to use [these settings](https://superuser.com/a/701484).

Answer (score 0):

Targeting all users but John Doe:

```
(?sm)^(?!Doe, John)[^\r\n]+:$\R(.*?(?=\R[^\r\n[]+\[.*:|\Z))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/fH0rK9/2)